# Method tracing on OpenJDK or Oracle JDK

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, java-opts

Does OpenJDK or Oracle JDK have a feature like ["method trace" on IBM JDK](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/trace_method_trace_run.html)?

Should I use AOP (for example, AspectJ)?

Comment: OpenJDK has everything needed for such tracing. There are JVMTI MethodEntry/MethodExit events, `-XX:+DTraceMethodProbes` for tracing with DTrace/SystemTap, Instrumentation API to inject tracing calls into the bytecode (that's how AspectJ works).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will check them.

Comment: If you are trying to debug a program, I would use a debugger.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No. I want to know execution time per method in a way as easy as possible.